# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.join is not a function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, azure-devops-extensions

I have an extension on devops azure, and I 'm newbie in Javascript by the way.
I wrote an function to get the name of task after fetch its id from server:

```js
dataService.getDocument("registryKey").then((doc) => {
    let authenToken =  doc.value[doc.count - 1];
    fetch('https://52.221.253.35/api/timelog'+query, {
       method: 'GET',
       headers:{
          'Authentication': authenToken
       }
   }).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function (data) {
         let index = 1;
         let body = "";
         // foreach the data and i call VSS Http to get work item 's detail
         data.forEach(async function f(item) {
             let result = await witClient.getWorkItems(item.TaskId, ["System.Id", "System.Title"]);
                        body+="<p>"+result['System.Title']+"</p>"
                    $("#table-body").html(body);
                });
```

but when it runs, it throws an error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.join is not a function`
What is wrong here? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Well whatever the problem is, it is not part of the code you have supplied.

Comment: i inspect chrome, and the console log throw the error indicate the error come from that code

Comment: Yes, but not in the code you provided, which I can tell because it does not contain `n.join`. So possibly it is in library code being called by your code. The stack trace should tell you what line of your code was responsible.

Comment: yes, thank you, i see, so it broken on this line: `witClient.getWorkItems(item.TaskId, ["System.Id", "System.Title"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let result = await witClient.getWorkItems([item.TaskId], ["System.Id", "System.Title"]);
                    body+="<p>"+result['System.Title']+"</p>"
                $("#table-body").html(body);
            });
```

Note the square brackets around the first parameter.

Comment: i try your solution, but when i debug, it jumped to `$("#table-body").html(body);` before jump on `body+="<p>"+result['System.Title']+"</p>"`

Comment: yes, but can you explain to me why it jump to `$("#table-body").html(body);` before `body+="<p>"+result['System.Title']+"</p>"`

Comment: I can't. Because you haven't supplied the code context. But that is a separate question - please post a new one if you can't work out what's going on.